# Excel Macro to concatenate

Tags: excel

Need help in creating an Excel Macro.I have an Excel sheet.The Excel sheet is not consistent.
I am planning to make it uniform and structured.

Eg.

```
  A            B            C         D
1 test      tester         tester
2 hai       test
3 Bye       test           tested
4 GN        test           tested    Fine

  A            B            C         D
1 test      testertester   
2 hai       test
3 Bye       testtested     
4 GN        testtestedFine
```

Basically I have to find the last cell where element is placed so based on that I can write my CONCATENATE funciton.

In this case it would be Column D and hence my concatenate function would have been
=CONCATENATE(B1,C1,D1)
Again I would like the result to be in B1 but not a problem if I have to hide.

Can anyone help me in doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following VBA function which joins (concatenates) the values from an arbitrary range of cells, with an optional delimiter.

```
Public Function Join(source As Range, Optional delimiter As String)
    Dim text As String
    Dim cell As Range: For Each cell In source.Cells
        If cell.Value = "" Then GoTo nextCell

        text = text & cell.Value & delimiter

nextCell:
    Next cell

    If text <> "" And delimiter <> "" Then
        text = Mid(text, 1, Len(text) - Len(delimiter))
    End If

    Join = text
End Function
```

For an example of how to use the function, enter =JOIN(A1:D1) into a cell anywhere on the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

=B1&C1&D1

or

Adam's function that I have optimized.

```
Function Join(source As Range, Optional delimiter As String) As String
'
' Join Macro
' Joins (concatenates) the values from an arbitrary range of cells, with an optional delimiter.
'

'optimized for strings
'   check len is faster than checking for ""
'   string Mid$ is faster than variant Mid
'   nested ifs allows for short-circuit
'   + is faster than &

    Dim sResult As String
    Dim oCell As Range

    For Each oCell In source.Cells
        If Len(oCell.Value) > 0 Then
            sResult = sResult + CStr(oCell.Value) + delimiter
        End If
     Next

    If Len(sResult) > 0 Then
        If Len(delimiter) > 0 Then
            sResult = Mid$(sResult, 1, Len(sResult) - Len(delimiter))
        End If
    End If

    Join = sResult
End Function
```

Comment: How to call the function from My excel sheet?

Comment: Just like AdamRalph mentioned.