# Concatenate Columns Of Data

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation

***Edited To Add: Current error I'm receiving. See bottom of this post for screenshot.**

I have text in column D. The macro should find blank cells, and then concatenate the text from all cells below it.

**Example**

Text starting in D2, displaying like this...

```
Blank Cell
SampleText1
SampleText2
SampleText3
Blank Cell
SampleText4
SampleText5
SampleText6
```

The macro *should* display the text in D2...

```
SampleText1, SampleText2, SampleText3
```

and then in D6, like this...

```
SampleText4, SampleText5, SampleText6
```

..and so on.

This only needs to work in column D, so I'm guessing I can write it to that range.

The closest answer I've come across is here:
[Excel Macro to concatenate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498555/excel-macro-to-concatenate)

**Here is the code I'm currently working with...**

```
Sub ConcatColumns()

   Do While ActiveCell <> ""  'Loops until the active cell is blank.

      'The "&" must have a space on both sides or it will be
      'treated as a variable type of long integer.

      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
         ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0)

      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   Loop

End Sub
```

**Edit: Now using great code from @jeeped but receiving an error, seen in the below screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Start from the bottom and work up, building an array of the strings. When you reach a blank cell, [Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b65z3h4h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) the strings using your preferred deliminator.

```
Sub build_StringLists()
    Dim rw As Long, v As Long, vTMP As Variant, vSTRs() As Variant
    Dim bReversedOrder As Boolean, dDeleteSourceRows As Boolean
    ReDim vSTRs(0)

    bReversedOrder = False
    dDeleteSourceRows = True

    With Worksheets("Sheet4")
        For rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(rw, 1)) Then
                ReDim Preserve vSTRs(0 To UBound(vSTRs) - 1)
                If Not bReversedOrder Then
                    For v = LBound(vSTRs) To UBound(vSTRs) / 2
                        vTMP = vSTRs(UBound(vSTRs) - v)
                        vSTRs(UBound(vSTRs) - v) = vSTRs(v)
                        vSTRs(v) = vTMP
                    Next v
                End If
                .Cells(rw, 1) = Join(vSTRs, ", ")
                .Cells(rw, 1).Font.Color = vbBlue
                If dDeleteSourceRows  Then _
                    .Cells(rw, 1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(vSTRs) + 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                ReDim vSTRs(0)
            Else
                vSTRs(UBound(vSTRs)) = .Cells(rw, 1).Value2
                ReDim Preserve vSTRs(0 To UBound(vSTRs) + 1)
            End If
        Next rw
    End With

End Sub
```

I've left options for reversing the string list as well as removing the original rows of strings.

[image: build_String_Lists_before]
            <sup>Before build_StringLists procedure</sup>

[image: build_String_Lists_After]
            <sup>After build_StringLists procedure</sup>

Comment: This looks great, thank you so much! You even anticipated my need to delete the rows afterwards! One question in implementing - what do I need to change? I've tried modifying just the reference to the sheet (i.e. changing "With Worksheets("Sheet4")" to my worksheet name) but I'm getting "Subscript out of range (Error 9)". Obviously this means I'm referencing something not included, but I am not skilled enough in VBA to modify your wonderful code here :) For my needs, it would be running on cells D2 - D39998.

Comment: Also, as I'm working with this more, you said you had left options for reversing and removing - what do I need to change, to implement the removing portion? I have other code written, which I did before this, but if you can accomplish this in one step, I would prefer that! Again, thank you so much. This is exactly what I need, and you responded very quickly!

Comment: ① See the [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) for how to change the row and column. ② See the two boolean variables `bReversedOrder` and `dDeleteSourceRows` to turn the option on and off.